# Does anyone use DD-WRT/OpenWRT etc. at their office?

Tags: wifi, router, tomato, openwrt

Does anyone use any of the third party router/AP firmwares (DD-WRT, OpenWRT, Tomato, etc.) in an office environment?
How many users does it handle well?
How long have you been using it?

I understand one of the risks is limited support but the cost savings could justify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use them everywhere, I think we got about a hundred used in production,
from simple firewalls to asterix nodes. We have standardized on ASUS WL-500GP
hardware. We have developed some scripts in-house to handle upgrades and "config"
snapshots. The only thing we really miss is accelerated crypto for OpenVPN.

Answer (score 6):

We have used DDWRT for over a year now and have never had an prob with it.  We run it on a WRT54G that is on and open to the public 24/7.  I may have had to restart it 3 times in the last year or so.  We frequently have 15-25 wireless users.

There is plenty of support for DDWRT online and I would definitely recommend it.  If you have read anything about it you know that it has a ton of features that just arent available anywhere else. (features here http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_%22DD-WRT%22%3F#Features )

I am also running it at home on the same router, which lives in my HOT attic.  The temperature doesnt seem to affect it at all, even under a heavy load.

Answer (score 3):

We use OpenWRT at work, both in the office and DC.  It'll handle as many machines as your wireless bandwidth will support, as far as I can tell.  I don't know how long we've been using it, it was here when I got here.

Answer (score 1):

We use DD-WRT on a Linksys router. It handles 20 users just fine, been using it for over a year, much more powerful than standard Linksys firmware.